# Tried to retrieve data in the database into my checkboxes, the problem is I can't insert the checked box into the database

Tags: php, html, laravel, web, checkbox

This is my code in blade

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="contact-form">
                        <form id="contact" action="{{url('/reservation')}}" method="post">
                        @csrf
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <h4>Reservation</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
                              <fieldset>
                                <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name*" >
                              </fieldset>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
                              <fieldset>
                              <input name="email" type="text" id="email" pattern="[^ @]*@[^ @]*" placeholder="Your Email Address" >
                            </fieldset>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
                              <fieldset>
                                <input name="phone" type="number" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number*" >
                              </fieldset>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                              
                                <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address">

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div id="filterDate2">    
                                  <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
                                    <input name="date" id="date" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
                                    <div class="input-group-addon" >
                                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>   
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                              
                                <input type="time" name="time">

                            </div>

         @foreach($data as $data)
         <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <p class='mybox text-dark'><input type="checkbox" name="productz[]" value="{{$data->title}}"/>{{$data->title}}</p>
                      </div>
          @endforeach
        </div>
                            <div class=" col-lg-12 mt-5">
                              <fieldset>
                                <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="main-button-icon">Make A Reservation</button>
                              </fieldset>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

THIS IS WHAT'S INSIDE MY MODEL

```
 <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Reservation extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Reservation extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

FOR MY CONTROLLER

```
$reservation = new reservation();
        $reservation->productz= implode(", " ,$request->productz);
        $reservation->save();
        return view('reservation');
    }
```

FROM MY MIGRATED TABLE

```
 <?php
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    
    class CreateReservationsTable extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('reservations', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('name')->nullable();
                $table->string('email')->nullable();
                $table->string('phone')->nullable();
                $table->string('address')->nullable();
                $table->string('date')->nullable();
                $table->string('time')->nullable();
                $table->string('productz')->nullable();
    
    
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
    
        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::dropIfExists('reservations');
        }
    }
```

Tried to look for tutorial similar to what I'm doing where I retrieved the data from the database such as title and inserted it to checkbox which is successfully displayed. But I can't insert the data checked into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `with` function, which adds a piece of data into your view, in conjunction with the `view` function.

So something like:

```
return view('reservation')->with('data', $reservation->productz);
```

should work. Also do make sure the name of each variable that you're looping over is different from the name of the array itself -> e.g. `foreach($datum as $data)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `print_r($request->productz)` and look the data from checkedbox is printing the correct data or not